# New XML node with IXML

Tags: c#, xml, microsoft-metro

I'm making a Windows 8 Metro Style test application using XML files. I have the reading of the file and nodes working including editing and deleting them.

The problem I'm facing now and can't figure out how to complete is the adding of a node.
Below here is the code I'm using for reading and saving.

```
private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<XmlDocument> LoadXML()
    {
        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
        StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("Settings.xml");
        var XmlFile = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(storageFile);
        return XmlFile;
    }

    private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SaveXML(XmlDocument XmlFile)
    {
        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
        StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("Settings.xml");
        await XmlFile.SaveToFileAsync(storageFile);

        MessageDialog Message = new MessageDialog("Data is saved/removed!", "Notification");
        await Message.ShowAsync();
    }
```

This part below is of an event which refers to the two above. In this part of the code do I need to add a new node based on information from a textbox.

```
    private async void btnSaveproject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var XmlFile = await LoadXML();

        await SaveXML(XmlFile);
    }
```

For those who wonder how I have done the removing and editing will I also add these part of the code right below here.

```
    // Removing
    IXmlNode Node = XmlFile.SelectSingleNode("XML").SelectSingleNode("List").SelectSingleNode(lvList.SelectedItem.ToString());
    XmlFile.SelectSingleNode("XML").SelectSingleNode("List").RemoveChild(Node);

    //Saving
    XmlFile.SelectSingleNode("XML").SelectSingleNode("Colors").SelectSingleNode("ColorR").InnerText = tbxColorR.Text;
```

Comment: Any reason you're using XmlDocument rather than LINQ to XML? I'd *expect* Metro to support the latter, and it's *much* cleaner than XmlDocument.

Comment: I figured out that I could have used Linq to read out the XML file but on that moment I had basically everything done except the adding of a new node. Also not fully sure if Linq is fully supported in Metro but I would be weird if it isn't.

Comment: Well it's not just LINQ, it's LINQ to XML. It's separate from the rest of LINQ, really - but it's *definitely* worth changing your code to use it if you can. Even if you're nearly there with your current code, every time you have to maintain it, it'll be painful compared with LINQ to XML.